# Django Signal Receiver Function not accepting sender

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, signals

I am trying to create notification whenever a user likes a post. For that I am using django signals. I have previously used the sender arguement in the receiver decorator but don't why its not working this time. Here are my files.

```
#core.signals.py
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Post)
def likeNotification(sender,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['action'] == "post_add" and not kwargs['reverse']:
        post = kwargs['instance']
        to_user = post.user
        liked_by_users = kwargs['pk_set']
        like_notification = [Notification(
            post=post,
            user=to_user, sender=User.objects.get(id=user),
            text=f"{User.objects.get(id=user).profile.username} liked your post.", noti_type=3
        ) for user in liked_by_users]
        Notification.objects.bulk_create(like_notification)
```

```
#socialuser.models.py
class Post(Authorable, Creatable, Model):
    caption = TextField(max_length=350, null=True, blank=True)
    liked_by = ManyToManyField(
        "core.User", related_name="like_post", blank=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def no_of_likes(self):
        return len(self.liked_by.all())
```

The receiver doesn't catch the signal when sender=Post, when I remove the sender it works as intended. On print the positional arguement sender of likeNotification function. This is what I get

```
<class 'socialuser.models.Post_liked_by'>
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to reference to the intermediate class Post_liked_by, if so how do I do that?

Comment: Do you have defined an `AppConfig`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yep I have configured the appconfig in the same app where I have placed my signals.py 

from django.apps import AppConfig
class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'core'

    def ready(self):
        # Implicitly connect a signal handlers decorated with @receiver.
        from core import signals`

this is what it looks... I think I don't need to do the same in socialuser appconfig...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Also, my signals.py is situated in core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the `through` model of the `ManyToManyField` of the model, so `Post.liked_by.through`, not `Post`: otherwise it is not clear on what `ManyToManyField` you are subscribing. We thus define the handler as:

```
#core/signals.py

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Post.liked_by.through)
def likeNotification(sender,**kwargs):
    # …
```

You can boost the efficiency to determine the number of likes with:

```
#socialuser/models.py

class Post(Authorable, Creatable, Model):
    # …

    def no_of_likes(self):
        return self.liked_by.count()
```

then it will determine the number of likes at the database side, and thus reduce the bandwidth from the database to the Django/Python application layer.